# how to embed an Icon in front of javafx treeItem's label.(except itself graphic)?

Tags: javafx

I want to embed an refresh Icon **in front of** each treeItem's label in javafx.
How can i do that?

```
private final Node rootIcon =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("topic.png")));

TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String>("root",rootIcon);
```

for example:

```
  private final Node rootIcon =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("topic.png")));
  ImageView icon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("refresh.png")));
  TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String>("root" + icon ,rootIcon);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej hossein,

i think you want to built something like this:

[image: Example]

I took two small images and created a new class `TopicPanel`, you can extend `Panel` and add two `ImageView`s to, for example a `HBox` and now you have one Topic Image and your Refresh Image..

Here is the Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class TopicPanel extends Pane {

    private ImageView topicImage;
    private ImageView refreshImage;
    private HBox pane;


    public TopicPanel(final String topicImageUrl) {
        try {

            pane = new HBox(5.0);
            this.refreshImage = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/ottp/MyCloud/TreeNodeExample/src/main/resources/refresh.png"))));

            this.topicImage = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(new File(topicImageUrl))));


            pane.getChildren().add(this.topicImage);
            pane.getChildren().add(this.refreshImage);

            this.getChildren().add(pane);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TopicPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

Here is a very simple example, how you can use this `TopicPanel` class in your App

```
import de.professional_webworkx.treenodeexample.domain.Person;
import de.professional_webworkx.treenodeexample.panes.TopicPanel;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();



        Person p = new Person("Patrick", "Tester", "patrick@example.com", null);
        Person p1 = new Person("Hans", "Meier", "hans@example.com", p);
        Person p2 = new Person("Karl", "Mueller", "karl@example.com", p);
        Person p3 = new Person("Heinz", "Glas", "heinzk@example.com", null);
        Person p4 = new Person("Beate", "Kriegtkeinab", "beate@example.com", p3);

        persons.add(p);
        persons.add(p1);
        persons.add(p2);
        persons.add(p3);
        persons.add(p4);

        Node images = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/ottp/MyCloud/TreeNodeExample/src/main/resources/alert.png"))));
        TreeItem<Person> rootNode = new TreeItem<>(p, images);
        for(Person person : persons) {
            if(person.getSuperior() != null && person.getSuperior().equals(p)) {
                Node img = new TopicPanel("/Users/ottp/MyCloud/TreeNodeExample/src/main/resources/alert.png");
                rootNode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(person, img));
            }
        }
        TreeView<Person> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);
        Scene scene = new Scene(treeView, 1024, 768);



        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you need the Domain Class `Person`

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    private Person superior;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Person superior) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.superior = superior;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 23 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.getFirstName());
        hash = 23 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.getLastName());
        hash = 23 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.getEmail());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.email, other.email)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "firstName=" + getFirstName() + ", lastName=" + getLastName() + ", email=" + getEmail() + '}';
    }

    /**
     * @return the superior
     */
    public Person getSuperior() {
        return superior;
    }

    /**
     * @param superior the superior to set
     */
    public void setSuperior(Person superior) {
        this.superior = superior;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you...

Patrick